# If some guy is a buff, does he "knows a lot" enough to get a professionals job?

Tags: meaning

per [cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-traditional/buff), a buff is

> a person who knows a lot about and is very interested in a particular subject

such as, computer buff, baseball buff.

If some guy is a computer buff, does he "knows a lot" enough to get a computer related job, like programmer?

Comment: It's not directly related being a buff and being a professional. It depends on the job. Can a baseball buff play in the World Series? Can a movie buff be the director of a film? If you are a gamer and you're very interested in video-games, it does not imply that you know how to program them, for example.

Comment: A computer buff might know a heckuva lot about computers, but have no idea how to put any of it into real world practice. *You could have a car buff who hasn't passed their driving licence*

Comment: We sometimes call military-history buffs "armchair generals".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the expression *computer buff* in a résumé if you are applying for a job in programming or in the field of IT in general. It is fine listed as a *hobby* or as an *intense interest* if applying for a different job, e.g. a managerial position, but *not* in place of a  formal qualification.

Comment: In Britain, we have a lot of what we call 'railway enthusiasts' ("rail buffs" to Americans), and believe me, rail companies do not like to see that on a resume.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey are you confirming and agreeing with me? I'm never 100 percent certain with some comments... *help*!

Comment: Mari-Lou A - I am 100% agreeing with you, that a hobby interest does not replace or substitute for a qualification, and adding my own 2 cents' worth that a strong hobby interest can be a warning light to an employer in some fields.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe yes, maybe no. Hobbyists tend to be knowledgeable in their comfort zone; a qualification provides evidence to an employer that an individual has had training in working with others, extending their capabilities and meeting imposed targets.

Comment: My own experience: nothing kills a hobby as much as getting a job in that field does.

Comment: I was 21, I loved motorcycles, and I got a job in a big motorcycle dealers, selling spare parts, Honda mainly, but some British makes too. After 3 months, I didn't want to hear about the damn things if I wasn't being paid to.